# What's the antonym for Schadenfreude?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Schadenfreude is the joy or pleasure derived from the misfortunes of others. What is the word for joy or pleasure derived from the happiness of others?

Comment: _Freudenfreude_?

Comment: **Wait!** Maybe this is a "even"/"odd" symmetry issue, but I would have thought that the **opposite** of Schadenfreude would be a word for "unhappiness at the good fortune of others," No?
I would really like to know what **that** word (in German, of course) would be.

Comment: Actually, the opposite of *Schadenfreude* would be the sadness about the harm of someone else. Thus, *Mitgefühl*/*compassion*, as aaamos mentioned, is the closest word that come to my mind.

Comment: @TMM **Envy**: *a feeling of discontent or covetousness with regard to another's advantages, success, possessions, etc.* (German: **Neid**)

Comment: might as well ask what's the opposite of a *duck*

Comment: @user20493 re: "unhappiness at the good fortune of others" - what is the German word for "social liberal progressive" or "registered democrat voter"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seeing just the title of your question ("What's the antonym for Schadenfreude?"), my answer would have been "Mitgefühl" (to keep it in German) or "compassion" (English), since I'd say that Schadenfreude is the *absence* of compassion.

Having now seen your description as wanting a word to express "joy or pleasure derived from the happiness of others", I'd say "Mitfreude" would be it in German, and "sympathetic joy" would be the closest I can think of in English (couldn't find a single word, though a bit of googling did turn up "Mudita" as per cornbread ninja's response, so +1 from me).

**Edit**:

Mitgefühl means "sadness derived from the sadness of others".

Schadenfreude means "joy derived from the misfortune of others".

Mudita/Mitfreude means "joy derived from the joy of others".

Comment: _Mitfreude_ is not a German word.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: ...that you know of. [Broaden your horizon](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/mitfreude): "Teilnahme an der Freude eines anderen, anderer".

Comment: @aaamos Well well. Learn something new every day...

Comment: +1, since *Mitgefühl*/*compassion* is the best word. You're right, that the explanation asks for something else, then the title expresses.

Comment: Just to have it here in plain text as a courtesy to future readers: *Mitgefühl* means "sadness derived from the sadness of others"; *schadenfreude* means "joy derived from the misfortune of others"; *mudita/mitfreude* mean "joy derived from the joy of others".

Comment: All these years later, I just learned today from a friend that there's an English word for _Schadenfreude_ that I never knew! [Epicaricacy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epicaricacy) - guess you learn something new every day... And it suddenly makes me wonder why English speakers use the German word for it. Apparently (from the usage notes), it wasn't used much "until it was picked up by various 'interesting word' websites around the turn of the twenty-first century".

Answer (score 11):

*[Mudita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudita)* is the Buddhist concept of joy.

> It is especially sympathetic or vicarious joy, the pleasure that
>   comes from delighting in other people's well-being rather than
>   begrudging it.

Comment: _Vicarious_ is what I would use.

Comment: _Vicariousness_ is merely a vehicle.  OP's request reaches beyond to feeling the opposite of schadenfreude as a result of the insight.

Comment: @cornbreadninja Mudita is close but does not directly answer my question. It's an interesting word though. So +1 from me. :)

Comment: *Vicarious* is still what I would use. It is by far the best fit that is a widely understood word; *vicarious pleasure* is what people actually say when they mean that in English. They have to do a little more explaining maybe, because it's not a perfect fit. Unfortunately there just isn't always a perfect fit.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with *mudita*, but [this 1871 definition](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cQ8JAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA405&dq=mudita&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PcpfT7O1PIW80QWQzJ2LBw&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=mudita&f=false) says it's *the meditation of joy, but ... not the joy arising from earthly possessions.* Personally I'm not sure it's really an English "word", nor does it seem to be (in its original sense, at least) particularly associated with vicariously experiencing pleasure directly experienced by another individual. In its Buddhist context, the priest aspiring to it should already have transcended concepts of individuality anyway.

I don't know a "proper" single-word term, but [empathic joy](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22The%20devil%27s%20in%20the%20detail%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22empathic%20joy%22&oq=%22empathic%20joy%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=4674l7161l10l7528l13l13l1l0l0l0l153l672l11.1l12l0&gs_l=serp.3...4674l7161l10l7528l13l13l1l0l0l0l153l672l11j1l12l0&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e2384ef21332d9&biw=1264&bih=902) and  [empathic pleasure](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22The%20devil%27s%20in%20the%20detail%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22empathic%20pleasure%22&oq=%22empathic%20pleasure%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=209808l212624l11l213518l11l11l3l0l0l0l55l305l8l8l0&gs_l=serp.3...209808l212624l11l213519l11l11l3l0l0l0l55l305l8l8l0&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e2384ef21332d9&biw=1264&bih=859) are reasonably common collocations (the first much discussed by psychologists, as the [empathic-joy hypothesis](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zdLxwAAjpxYC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=empathic%20joy%20hypothesis&source=bl&ots=GpK2b6cpaU&sig=jUvu_je-YyK0n4OEXeiytzLBJVY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fs1fT_PAE8S80QW3yeGVBw&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=empathic%20joy%20hypothesis&f=false)).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the word [Compersion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compersion) perhaps.

From Wiktionary:

> The feeling of joy one has experiencing another's joy, such as in witnessing a toddler's joy and feeling joy in response.

Comment: I'd be careful with that one, as it has a different meaning than the one you quote. :-) The definition on wiktionary reads: "Vicarious joy associated with seeing one's partner have a joyful romantic or sexual relation with another."

Answer (score 2):

As the Corndog Ninja noted, *[mudita](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/various/wheel170.html)* is the concept of finding joy in the happiness of others.

If you want a rough German antonym of *Schadenfreude* (or simply schadenfreude in English texts -- "enjoyment obtained from the mishaps of others," as Merriam-Webster defines it), then *Seligkeitfreude* would work.

Comment: as long as you don't call me [corndog man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0193837/).  :)

Comment: I don't believe that word exists as a compound noun in German, but if it did, it would have an 's' to join them, as in _Seligkeitsfreude_. Also, the word wouldn't express whether the joy (Freude) is directed at the bliss (Seligkeit) of others or one's own.

Comment: @cornbreadninja Ooops, my bad! But I'll let it stand unedited, if you don't mind :D

Comment: Please let it stand unedited; I want this comment string to make sense for future generations.  :D

Answer (score 2):

The word **confelicity** has been suggested for this concept, most recently [by Susie Dent](https://twitter.com/susie_dent/status/919471913491206144) - however, real-world usage of it (outside of collections of obscure words) seems to be scant to non-existent, and it isn't found in any mainstream dictionaries.

> **Etymology**
>
> From the Latin prefix con- (from Latin cum (“with”)) + the Latin felicitas (“happiness”).
>
> **Noun**
>
> confelicity (uncountable)
>
> (rare) Pleasure in another's happiness.

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confelicity))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *goodwill*? Defined as:

- Friendly, helpful, or cooperative feelings or attitude.
- A kindly feeling of approval and support : benevolent interest or concern

Or *graciousness*.

Answer (score 0):

[***Solidarity***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/solidarity)

> Unity or agreement of feeling or action, especially among individuals with a common interest; mutual support within a group: ‘factory workers voiced solidarity with the striking students’

*(Oxford)*

In Spanish this word has a strong connotation with *empathy*.  I'm not really sure if it would be understand the same way in English.

Also, you can say,

> Lisa always ***celebrates others' successes***.