# What do you call a person who takes pleasure in the success of others?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the antonym for Schadenfreude?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61008/whats-the-antonym-for-schadenfreude)

I often like to watch the successful moments in the events of sportsmen and I take great pleasure in seeing them succeed so much. What is this called?

Comment: Possible duplicate, but this title is much clearer than that.

Comment: Well I will use the word friend. Friends always share joy and misfortune.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed at length [here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61008/whats-the-antonym-for-schadenfreude) The Buddist concept of [Mudita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudita) comes close to describing the joy at others' success.

Answer (score 2):

It can be called [symhedonia (sympathy for another's good fortune)](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/emo/6/1/82/), sympathetic joy, or empathic joy. (The latter two terms yield many Google results.)