# How to express happiness on someone's failure?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

Documentation of StackOverflow is finally gone, and I am happy about it. StackOverflow was meant to be a Q/A site, and it is, in fact, the top site in its category. But *Docs* is not something it should be doing. Every project have their own documentation which is good in itself.

I want to express the feeling that I'm happy it is gone. *Happy* is so generic for this. *Grin* is also not one of it. Please also note that I have a negative context.

And please, I really like SO, I don't hate it. I just want to improve my vocab.

EDIT:

This question is not as same as [What do you call a person who takes pleasure in the success of others?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/69175/19868) because that question completely different. It deals with happiness which is caused by the success of others, and this question is more like happiness in the failure of others.

Comment: How could be a duplicate of that question, I'm not taking pleasure in *success*, rather pleasure in *failure*. Edited question for the explanation.

Comment: Oops, you are totally right, my close vote retracted. There are approximately 150 question already with Schadenfreude in the question or answer ... trust me to pick the one for my close vote looking for an antonym of Schadenfreude ! Anyway I still think there are plenty of dups to choose.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. Makes me kinda sad.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate of something. There are 143 hits for [schadenfreude](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=schadenfreude).

Comment: Honestly this question shows no real effort to look for an answer. Simply looking up [Word for happiness in others failure](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+for+happiness+in+others+failure) (which is basically the title of this question) gives “schadenfreude” as the first two hits. EDIT: found the dupe (fourth hit on google): https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43771

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The word you're looking for might be:

> Schadenfreude

Definition by Merriam-Webster:

> enjoyment obtained from the troubles of others

Definition by dirctionary.com:

> noun
>
> 1. satisfaction or pleasure felt at someone else's misfortune.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCQGQ5qBQTA (don't listen to this song at work, though)

Comment: Tho' in the specific case of SO Docs, there really isn't any "trouble of others" (one would hope).

Comment: I think this would be a great answer for a German stack exchange, but it's not really in wide usage in English.

Comment: @DonJewett On the contrary, it has become a pretty popular loanword lately. I know that I have heard it a few times from English speakers. I just don't think it is a good fit for the OP's specific situation since SO Documentation isn't a person.

Comment: @KodosJohnson [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com.sg/trends/explore?q=Schadenfreude). It was quite popular in November 2016.

Answer (score 19):

While it does not name the emotion itself, a common saying in this sort of circumstance is **good riddance**.  "Riddance" means (OED)

> A deliverance or relief which consists in getting rid of something. Frequently with modifying adjective, as good, happy, etc.

In context:

> S. Rushdie, *Satanic Verses* i. iv. 79:   "He was glad to have seen the back of his badly behaved colleagues; good riddance to bad rubbish, he thought."

The extended phrase **good riddance to bad rubbish** is also in frequent usage, though my impression is that it is more common in British English than in American English.  Someone who says "good riddance" upon learning that they are rid of something is very obviously happy that it is gone.

Comment: Said phrase was culturally appropriated by Green Day.   :-)

Answer (score 8):

If your joy is derived in large part from being right about thinking that it would be a failure, I might go with **vindicated**:

> **[vindicate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vindicate)** 
>   VERB
>   1 Clear (someone) of blame or suspicion.
>   1.1 Show or prove to be right, reasonable, or justified. *'more sober views were vindicated by events'*

It's that later definition which you're invoking. You had a point of view (that StackOverflow shouldn't be doing documentation). However, other people didn't necessarily agree with your point of view. Now that it has failed, you are happy that your original prediction turned out to be correct. As such, you were shown to be right, reasonable and justified in your beliefs and predictions, and thus were *vindicated*.

While not directly an emotion word (it doesn't strictly speaking have anything to do with happiness), the feeling of happiness at being proved right is universal enough that the word "vindication" carries with it a positive connotation. A native English speaker, when hearing "*I felt vindicated when StackOverflow Documentation failed*", would understand it to mean that you were happy at StackOverflow Documentation's failure.

Answer (score 6):

I like **Gratifying**.

*Gratifying*:  giving pleasure or satisfaction. [Webster's]

*Gratifying* is nice because it has the potential for negative connotations.

(positive)   *My promotion was gratifying because I worked really hard for it.*

(negative)  *Watching the bully fall down the stairs was totally gratifying.*

Answer (score 5):

I expect that you are feeling **[relief](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/relief)** with the decision, which one can argue is not relief because of some failure, but rather relief in response to a successful return to core principles.

> **[relief](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/relief)**
>   NOUN *[mass noun]*
>   1 A feeling of reassurance and relaxation following release from anxiety or distress.
>   *‘much to her relief, she saw the door open’*

Comment: *I want to express the feeling that I'm happy it is gone.* - I'd appreciate the downvoters explaining why *relief* doesn't answer this question (which is different from the title of the post).

Answer (score 4):

**[To Gloat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gloat#English)**, or **[Gloating](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gloat#English)**

1. To exhibit a conspicuous (sometimes malevolent) pleasure or sense of self-satisfaction, often at an adversary's misfortune.
2. To triumph, crow, relish, glory, revel in.