# A word for being troubled at others' potential schadenfreude against me

Tags: single-word-requests, subject-verb-inversion

Schadenfreude is "enjoyment obtained from the trouble of others." I'm not looking for the antonym of that, but instead if there is a similar word for the *object* of schadenfreude. For instance, is there a word for me knowing (or being troubled that) others are experiencing schadenfreude at my expense?

Comment: It depends on what troubles the "object" is having. I can't think of something better than the periphrastic "happy at my expense."

Comment: BTW there is a Greek cognate: epicaricacy

Comment: Embarrassment/humiliation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the antonym for Schadenfreude?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61008/whats-the-antonym-for-schadenfreude)

Comment: @MattЭллен: The OP clearly says he does not want the antonym; besides this question is very different IMHO.

Comment: @Shyam true, I've edited the title so it's more applicable.

Answer (score 3):

'Schadenfreude' is a German word. 'Opfer' i.e. victim, describes the person suffering from schadenfreude.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of *self-pity* encompasses negative feelings by the suffering person, but it primarily concerns the source of the pain, rather than additional pain based on others' enjoyment. [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/self-pity) defines it as

> care and sadness about your own problems

At times, those who are identified as *self-pitying* are even thought to take some satisfaction in their suffering. [American Heritage](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/self-pity) defines it as

> Pity for oneself, especially exaggerated or self-indulgent pity.

*Martyrdom* is similarly used to refer to those who suffer and perhaps derive some self aggrandizement in their suffering.  Compact OED offers, as one definition of *martyr*

> a person who displays or exaggerates their discomfort or distress in order to obtain sympathy

Again, the word does not generally convey an enhanced pain based on others' joy.

Answer (score 2):

Riffing off @WolfSchumacher’s answer, you’re after a fear (*Angst*) of being the victim (*Opfer*) of schadenfreude (*Schadenfreude*).  German being famous for its compounds, you could coin:

> Schadenfreudenopferangst

It’s preposterous, but *Schadenopfer* (victim of damages), *Opferangst* (fear of victimhood) and *Freudenangst* (fear of joy) are all attested to varying degrees.

The resulting term would, of course, be entirely incomprehensible to English speakers, however.  An all-Greek offering isn’t much better *epicaricacothymophobia* (working off mac389’s comment).  And maximizing parts familiar to English speakers hardly improves things: I don’t see *schadenfreudothymophobia* taking off any time soon.