# Schadenfreude and its direct opposite

Tags: antonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A word for being troubled at others' potential schadenfreude against me](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79526/a-word-for-being-troubled-at-others-potential-schadenfreude-against-me)

This is the ability to laugh at others' misfortune.  What word would you use if you knew that your misfortune was causing others to laugh at you?  Example; standing huddled in the rain to have a cigarette, knowing that your friends are inside in the warm.

Comment: Looks like we need a [corollary] tag; this isn't really an antonym. However: interesting question. Neither *embarrassment* nor *ruefulness* quite cut it.

Comment: The example you describe doesn't raise schadenfreude. - Schadenfreude rather come up, for instance, when the person standing in the rain has missed the bus.

Comment: related: [A word for being troubled at others' potential schadenfreude against me](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79526/a-word-for-being-troubled-at-others-potential-schadenfreude-against-me) | [What's the antonym for Schadenfreude?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61008/whats-the-antonym-for-schadenfreude) | [A different sort of antonym for Schadenfreude?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/a-different-sort-of-antonym-for-schadenfreude) | [Not “schadenfreude”, but related?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49949/not-schadenfreude-but-related)

Comment: something near melancholy, melodrama, and pathos?

Comment: However, @AndrewLeach, *embarrassment* is quite good. I'd add *shame*.

Comment: *Embarrassment* or *chagrin* might do.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to offer this word as it is neither an antonym nor an inverse.

sardonic (adjective)

> characterized by bitter or scornful derision; mocking; cynical; sneering

(from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sardonic))

> "As the rain progressed from a drizzle to downpour, Bill nursed his cigarette with sardonic bitterness. He knew his non-smoking friends were surreptitiously watching him from the warm, dry, fourteenth floor."

This would work if Bill had a sense of self-relief in his friends' *schadenfreude*.