# What's a word for someone who enjoys giving others pleasure?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What's a word for someone who enjoys giving others pleasure?

**Basically the opposite of schadenfreude**, schadenfreude being pleasure derived from the misfortunes of others.

I'm looking for a word **that means pleasure derived from giving others pleasure.**

EDIT
Did a bunch more googling and found the answer. I don't know how to delete this question though. 
[What's the antonym for Schadenfreude?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61008/whats-the-antonym-for-schadenfreude)

Comment: Don't delete it! It will help other readers to find the other answer. The more routes there are to get there the more helpful it is. So your question wasn't in vain! :)