# What is a word for "to take pleasure in someone else's success"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, say I work with a group of people, and one completes a very successful project. If I feel happy that a teammate has had a success I then I am…..?

Comment: How about 'happy'?

Comment: ..happy for them about their success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be similar to this question, [What's the antonym for Schadenfreude?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61008/whats-the-antonym-for-schadenfreude)

With the two most up-voted answers being [Mitgefühl](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mitgef%C3%BChl) (a German word for "compassion") and [Mudita](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/various/wheel170.html) (a Buddhist term for "finding joy in the happiness and success of others").

Comment: An antonym for Schadenfreude is perfect. Mudita is closest to what I was thinking.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible that you are ***vicariously happy***. Something that is vicarious is, according to [Merriam-Webster](http://i.word.com/idictionary/vicarious),

> experienced or felt by watching, hearing about, or reading about
>   someone else rather than by doing something yourself.

So, to be *vicariously happy* is to be happy for someone else's achievement as though it were your own.

Comment: Actually I don't think vicarious is used this way.

Comment: @Pacerier - Really? Sounds fine to me. It was exactly what I thought of when reading the question, and I was tempted to write the answer myself until I found someone else had.

Comment: Vicarious pleasure is widely used as well

Answer (score 3):

compersion - wiktionary

The feeling of joy one has experiencing another's joy, such as in witnessing a toddler's joy and feeling joy in response.
The feeling of joy associated with seeing a loved one love another; contrasted with jealousy.

Comment: An excellent find. Compersion should be a word of the day.

Comment: @E.Groeg, clare, **However,** note though that this word is oft-used in sentences which include words like <[polyfidelity](https://archive.is/qZd1s#selection-581.68-589.36)>. It's better to simply use <happy for him>, or if you need a single word, you'd much rather use the word [Mudita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudita)

Answer (score 1):

If I feel happy that a teammate has been successful then I am **happy for him**.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the word <compersion> is  oft-used in sentences which include words like <[polyfidelity](https://archive.is/qZd1s#selection-581.68-589.36)>.

To avoid such notions, you may want to stick to <happy for him>, or if you need a single word, you'd much rather use the word <[Mudita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudita)>.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised to not see *naches* on this list. It's a loan-word from Yiddish, usually used for mentees or ones children, to express the happiness felt when they succeed.

> ***Naches***, n.
>
> *Feeling of contentment at another's successes.*
>
> <sub>– https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/naches</sub>