# Is there a term for feeling satisfied with other people's improvement?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I don't really know why, and I don't see it as a bad thing, but I was just curious as to whether there is a word or phrase for feeling satisfied with other people's improvement. I like watching people improve, be it through their own efforts or with my assistance.
Is there a word for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/61008/112436

Answer (score 1):

[Altruism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/altruism)

> noun
>
> the principle or practice of unselfish concern for or devotion to the welfare of others (opposed to [egoism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/egoism) ).

[Philanthropy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/philanthropy?s=t)

> noun
>
> altruistic concern for human welfare and advancement, usually manifested by donations of money, property, or work to needy persons, by endowment of institutions of learning and hospitals, and by generosity to other socially useful purposes.

[Selflessness](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/selflessness?s=t)

> adjective
>
> having little or no concern for oneself, especially with regard to fame, position, money, etc.; unselfish.

[Benevolence](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/benevolence)

> noun
>
> desire to do good to others; goodwill; charitableness

Synonyms include

amity, comity, compassion, feeling, friendliness, friendship, generosity, gift, good will, goodness, humanity, kindheartedness, kindness, sympathy

Comment: Shame I can't up-vote for each if they answers there.