# What is a word for "the feeling of wanting something good for others"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms, emotions, abstract-nouns

I'm looking for a word that is the inverse of *envy*, in which a person wants others to have something good that they don't have.

The definition of envy from *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/envy)*:

> A feeling of discontented or resentful longing aroused by someone else's possessions, qualities, or luck.

In the word I'm looking for, a person sees something good and wants another person, who doesn't have it, to get it.

For example:

> I have such ______. I want them to have peace.

Comment: There are synonyms for _saintliness_ [here](https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/saintliness).

Comment: That's what _love_ means, among other things. As Borges put it, he was thankful "por el amor, que nos deja ver a los otros como los ve la divinidad."

Comment: Altruism? Kindness? Neighborliness? Empathy? Generosity?

Comment: Welcome @lee-c ! This other question may have what you're looking for: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61008/whats-the-antonym-for-schadenfreude

Comment: Looking at the post.. "Mitgefühl means "sadness derived from the sadness of others".. comes close but still doesn't convey a wanting of good for another.. I think in the sense of sadness at others sadness, it would cover it. Thank you for that bit. I still looking for a something to fit "yearning for good for another person"

Comment: I think that your question is unclear. The most obvious fit for your example is "sympathy", but that doesn't necessarily mean wanting something good for another person, which is more like "altruism". English may not have a word that means what you want.

Comment: The example is absurd. Someone attributing a quality to their own character is clearly not thinking much about others.

Answer (score 3):

**Benevolence**

desire to do good to others; goodwill; charitableness:

*to be filled with benevolence toward one's fellow creatures.*

an act of kindness; a charitable gift:

*She bequeathed many benevolences from her vast fortune.*

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/benevolence

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I don't think there is a word for this concept. When I think of desire for food, I am hungry. Desire for drink , thirsty. What is "the desire for something good for another person or people". I am "  "?

Comment: @Leec: Altruistically inclined.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ***selflessness*** is the most fitting word. A *selfless* person cares more about other people's needs, happiness, interests, problems etc. than their own. It is also an apt word as an opposite of *envy*.

The definition of *selflessness* from *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/selflessness)*:

> Concern more with the needs and wishes of others than with one's own. 
> *‘a noble act of selflessness’*

The differences from similar words:

- *Altruism* is also the concern for the well-being of others but it doesn't have to involve being *selfless*. One can still be motivated by their own desires and also help others. Altruistic people *can* become selfless though.
- *Sympathy* is more about sharing the same feelings with others, it is a feeling of pity or sense of compassion. It doesn't necessarily involve that you want them to have something good that you don't have. *Empathy* is similar also, which is the capacity to understand what another person is experiencing.
- *Generosity* is the willingness to give or share, more than usual or expected. It generally involves more tangible things, however, it can also refer to kindness in general but less commonly.
- *Unselfishness* is possibly the closest one. There are subtle differences though. Being unselfish is willing to share what you have also, but not necessarily beyond your own means. Being selfless goes beyond that and involves giving up good things and wanting others to have it.
- *Self-sacrifice* is very similar but it goes beyond *selflessness*. It is probably too strong for the context. It can involve sacrificing anything and everything for others, and it can reach to the point where you give up your life.